# Split values in the same row form a df in multiple columns by the same value?

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe has a column with some values, these values can apper in all rows, but is not required.
I want to split this values in different rows, putting 1 if the value apper in that column

I am using python 3 and the df is:

```py
data = {'Amenities':[{'TV', 'Wifi'}, {'TV',"Cable TV",'Internet','Wifi'},
                     {'Internet','Wifi'}]}  
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data) 
df2

    Amenities
0   {TV, Wifi}
1   {TV, Cable TV, Wifi, Internet}
2   {Wifi, Internet}
```

I would like to see a table in this way:

```py
data = {'Amenities':[{'TV', 'Wifi'}, {'TV',"Cable TV",'Internet','Wifi'},
                     {'Internet','Wifi'}],
        'TV':[1,1,0],
        'Cable TV':[0,1,0],
        'Wifi':[1,1,1],
        'Internet':[0,1,1],
       }  
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data) 
df2

    Amenities   TV  Cable TV    Wifi    Internet
0   {TV, Wifi}  1   0   1   0
1   {TV, Cable TV, Wifi, Internet}  1   1   1   1
2   {Wifi, Internet}    0   0   1   1
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case using `get_dummies` then `concat`

```
s=pd.get_dummies(df2.Amenities.apply(list).apply(pd.Series),prefix = '',prefix_sep = '').sum(level=0,axis=1)
s
Out[66]: 
   Cable TV  Internet  TV  Wifi
0         0         0   1     1
1         1         1   1     1
2         0         1   0     1
df=pd.concat([df2,s],axis=1)
df
Out[68]: 
                        Amenities  Cable TV  Internet  TV  Wifi
0                      {TV, Wifi}         0         0   1     1
1  {Cable TV, Internet, Wifi, TV}         1         1   1     1
2                {Internet, Wifi}         0         1   0     1
```